# Finding Tin Number From String

Tags: java, regex

I want to find tin number from a String of specific pattern where tin number start with with 8 or 9

```
input:
sample1="passport=11231&tin=91312312313&dl=12313"
sample2="tin=81312312314&dl=12313&passport=11231"
sample3="dl=12313&passport=11231&tin=71312312313"

Expected output:
91312312313
81312312314
false

Current output:
91312312313
81312312314
71312312313
```

I  have tried that, but it returns tin numbers that doesn't start with 8 or 9

```
tin=(.*?)[$&]
```

Edit: Please note that, tin number can contain a-zA-Z too but will always start with digit

Comment: Simply put a `[89]` after `tin=(`.

Answer (score 2):

How about something simple like

```
tin=[89]\d*
```

If you want to hold this number in group use

```
tin=([89]\d*)
```

If value doesn't need to hold only digits then instead of `\d` you can use `[^&$]` or maybe even `[^&]` since I don't see any `$` in your example.

```
tin=([89][^&$]*)
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for tin numbers that contain non digit, that is why i kept it wild not limiting to \d when i tried

Comment: @abdurrahim your example didn't show any of such values. Will update answer to handle this.

Comment: Thanks it works now.... I tried to upvote but I cant upvote anybody as, I am a rookie :|

Comment: @abdurrahim No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with that:

```
tin=((?=8|9).*?)[$&]
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/GVGvqA/1)